# Sending JSON via AJAX to PHP using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send JSON to a PHP file using jQuery AJAX, basically what I am trying to do is get the values and id's of a bunch of child elements and then assign them to a JSON object and then send that object via ajax to the PHP file which would then process it and enter it into a database.

Here is my code,

Javascript/jQuery:

```
function test(){
    var selects = $('#systems_wrapper').find('.dropDowns');
    var newArray = new Array();

    selects.each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();
        var o = { 'id': id, 'value': val };

        newArray.push(o);
    });

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "qwer.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { json: newArray }
        });

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST['json'];
    $person = json_decode($json);

    $file = fopen('test.txt','w+');
    fwrite($file, $person);
    fclose($file);

    echo 'success?';
?>
```

It creates the file, but it is completely blank, any idea what it could be?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: In your `<?php ?>` debug with `print_r($_POST);` to check if JS is ok. And you don't need `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()`

Comment: I am getting an array in return, Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => mail_1
            [value] => 150 Litre Cobra (G2)
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => mail_2
            [value] => CPC1518
        )

), I am struggling to process it though, could I access the array like so, $array[0]['id'] for instance?

Comment: When I print_r($_POST) though I get this... Array
(
    [json] => [{"id":"mail_1","value":"150 Litre Cobra (G1)"},{"id":"mail_2","value":"200 Litre Cobra (G1)"}]
)

Comment: You're trying to write an array data structure to a text format.

Comment: @Gutzofter, yeah I figured that, finally got it to work though, it was a stupid mistake, but thanx for the info guys! :)

Answer (score 19):

You could try using the `JSON.stringify()` method to convert your array into JSON automagically. Just pass the output from this.

```
data:  { json: JSON.stringify(newArray) }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @jish Just did. New favorite word. Beats flub.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an array.
use a simple string like this:

```
var o = '[';
selects.each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    o += '{ "id": "'+id+'", "value": "'+val+'" },';    
});
o = o.substring(0,o.length-1);
o += ']';
```

and in the ajax just send the string 'o'

```
        data: { json: newArray }
```

in the php file just make a json_decode($json, true);
it will return an array of array that you can access by a foreach
if you want to see the array, use var_dump($person);

Answer (score 1):

You should set a contentType on your ajax POST. I would use contentType: "application/json";

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_encode()` not `json_decode()`! This way you will get the json string and be able to write it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use json_decode if you're saving it to a text file.  jQuery is encoding your array in JSON format, PHP should then just write that format right to the text file.  When you want to open that file and access the data in a usable way, read its contents into a variable and THEN run json_decode() on it.